# Can't add "transform" to css to have custom Bootstrap modal animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've got a button in my page. It's `onclick` method is this:

```
function showModal(){
    $(".modal.fade.in .modal-dialog").css({"transform": "translate(50px, 10px)"});
    alert($("modal.fade.in .modal-dialog").css("transform"));
    $('#mymodal').modal('show');
}
```

I can't figure out why the alert says `undefined`. I can't seem to add transform attribute. `#mymodal` appears without that transform.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$("modal.fade.in .modal-dialog").css("transform")` will return `undefined` that's normal. It won't return neither `true` nor `error`, that's one. For the transform CSS, try wrapping your your transform (add vendor for webkit and Mozilla) into a CSS class, I highly recommend creating a Fiddle for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.in` class gets added to the `.modal` class only after it is being opened.

When you call `$(".modal.fade.in .modal-dialog").css({"transform": "translate(50px, 10px)"});` the selector returns an empty array.

You cannot make it work even if in `showModal()` function you called `$('#myModal').modal('show');` first. That is because the `.in` class is added when the modal loads which takes some milliseconds due to the animation when the modal opens.

To make it work remove the `.in` class from your selectors

```
function showModal() {
    $(".modal.fade .modal-dialog").css({"transform": "translate(50px, 10px)"});
    alert($("modal.fade .modal-dialog").css("transform"));
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

[Here](http://www.bootply.com/p5al3S7p3i) is a demo in bootply. As you can see there, the CSS transformation is added when the page loads and when you click to open the modal, the alert contains the transformation that is set.

**Edit**: As an empirical rule, I have seen that one cannot assign transitions by setting them via the use of `.css()`. What I usually do is create CSS classes that have these transitions and add the class to the element I want to make it.

**CSS**:

```
.effect1.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
     transform: scale(0.1); transition: all 1s; 
}

.effect1.modal.fade.in .modal-dialog { 
    transform: translate(500px, 50px); 
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function showModal() {
    $('#myModal').addClass('effect1');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

So, take a look [here](http://www.bootply.com/oVdtpVQyow) where I have created in CSS two effects, `.effect1` and `.effect2`. On the button click I set the class I need and then open the modal window.

**Edit2**: Since what you want is to use dynamic values in `x` and `y` we need to take another approach.

The following snippet uses the `shown.bs.modal` and `hidden.bs.modal` events to set and unset (important!!) the custom CSS rule.

Another important point is **to remove** the `.fade` class from the modal because that creates a conflict.

Now, you only need to apply your logic in the `getTransform()` function to return any `transform` value you need. The use of `flag` is for the demo only.

```
var flag = false;

function getTransform() {
  flag = !flag;
  return (flag ? "translate(500px, 50px)" : "translate(200px, 20px)");
};

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#myModal .modal-dialog").css({"transform": getTransform() });
});

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#myModal .modal-dialog").css({"transform": "" });
});

jQuery('#open1').click(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Take a look [here](http://www.bootply.com/32JzXno9dx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried what you said but it didn't work. I try to make the modal look like it's coming out from the button which was clicked. That's why I tried to edit `.modal.fade.in`. Is there anything I can try for this? If I enter the transform to css file by hand it works as expected. But it has to be depending on the button position.

Comment: @JohnMatters I added a link to see that the alert has a value and not undefined. Can you provide the CSS rule that make the effect to work?

Comment: .modal.fade .modal-dialog {
 transform: scale(0.1);
 transition: all 1s;
}

.modal.fade.in .modal-dialog {
    transform: translate(500px, 50px);
}

Comment: But I need to change x and y values of translate function dynamically in javascript, because they need to be calculated according to the position of the button. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @JohnMatters I updated my answer, hopefully this will be ok :)

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! But I have two questions: 1. Page immediately scrolls to top when I click the button. How can I prevent this? 2. Is there a way to get fade animations back? I could get modal fade in animation with changing opacity myself but couldn't make dropback and fade out animations work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93920/discussion-between-tasos-k-and-john-matters).

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to use JavaScript for that, CSS will do the job:

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(50px, 10px);
      -ms-transform: translate(50px, 10px);
       -o-transform: translate(50px, 10px);
          transform: translate(50px, 10px);
}
```

Your code does not work because you use `fade.in` instead of `.fade`.

```
function showModal(){
    $(".modal.fade .modal-dialog").css({"transform": "translate(50px, 10px)"});
    $('#mymodal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to edit the modal animation everytime so that it'll look like it is appearing from the button that was clicked.

Comment: I understand now, you did not mention that in your topic.